# Masstransit Passing Credential Issue

Tags: masstransit

Currently I am facing issue with masstransit passing default role credential, and my application code deploys into EKS container and EKS container attach with iam role.

iam role has full access to sqs service queue. Using this configuration without masstransit I am able to push message to queue using default credential option.

Can you please guide to configure masstransit in EKS container with specific role?

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use the instance credentials to configure the host:

```
cfg.Host("us-east-2", h =>
{
    h.Credentials(new InstanceProfileAWSCredentials());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

While @chris-patterson's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63034260/20619364) does work for a node IAM role, the question asks about a container-specific role.

It is possible to do this in EKS by attaching an IAM role to a service account, then configuring a pod with the service account and desired container image. This page describes something similar to what I did: https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-use-aws-iam-role-on-aws-eks-pods

Then in MassTransit you can assume the service account role as follows:

```cs
if (EC2InstanceMetadata.Region is { } ec2InstanceRegion)
{
    var creds = new AssumeRoleWithWebIdentityCredentials(
        "/var/run/secrets/eks.amazonaws.com/serviceaccount/token",
        ARN_OF_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_ROLE,
        null);
    sqsConfig.Host(ec2InstanceRegion.SystemName, awsConfig => awsConfig.Credentials(creds));
}
```

You'll need to install the `AWSSDK.SecurityToken` NuGet package. And in case you're wondering, the path string comes from the AWS docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/pod-configuration.html

By the way, while developing locally I've been using LocalStack and I was initially stuck on how to configure that too. So for good measure, here's my local config:

```cs
const int localStackPort = 4566;
var serviceUrl = $"http://localhost:{localStackPort}";
sqsConfig.Host(
    new UriBuilder("amazonsqs", "localhost", localStackPort).Uri,
    awsConfig =>
    {
        awsConfig.Config(
            new AmazonSimpleNotificationServiceConfig { ServiceURL = serviceUrl });
        awsConfig.Config(new AmazonSQSConfig { ServiceURL = serviceUrl });
        awsConfig.Credentials(new AnonymousAWSCredentials());
    });
```