# Masstransit with Amazon SQS not working in EKS

Tags: amazon-sqs, amazon-sns, amazon-eks, masstransit

I have configured the bus like this

```
services.AddMassTransit(x =>
        {
            x.UsingAmazonSqs((context, cfg) =>
            {
                cfg.Durable = true;
                cfg.AutoDelete = false;

                cfg.Host("us-east-2", h =>
                {
                });
            });
        });
```

I've not specified credential to allow AWS SDK to resolve the credential automatically.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/creds-assign.html

The setup works fine on my local machine with a AWS session profile. However when I deploy the code in EKS, I got the following message:

> Health check masstransit-bus with status Degraded completed after 1.9351ms with message 'Degraded Endpoints: {{THE BUS ENDPOINT}}'

There's no other error or warning, but the bus is not working. I have verified IRSA (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/iam-roles-for-service-accounts.html)  has been configured correctly for the pod.

Am I missing something? What can I do to track down the underlying issue?

Comment: Same question, same answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/63034260/1882

Comment: @ChrisPatterson Tested this, the role resolved using InstanceProfileAWSCredentials is the node role, not the IAM role attached to the service account. It throws AuthorizationErrorException because the node is not configured to have sqs/sns access. According to this https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/issues/1413#issuecomment-573019373, the sqs/sns client should just work without specifying the credentials.

Comment: No clue, I don't think any credentials are specified by default. The [source](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/tree/develop/src/Transports/MassTransit.AmazonSqsTransport/Configuration/Configurators) might help you understand how the configuration code interacts with the SDK.

Comment: @ChrisPatterson Figured it out. I was using ConnectClientFactory to create the request client, this works for rabbit and SQS in local environment, for some reason it doesn't work in containers.

Comment: Seems like a permission problem, if it's unable to create the temporary response queue. Or maybe the response queue name is too long?